# Installing stuff in Eclipse - No repository found "osgi.bundle"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

When I am installing stuff (paxRunner for example) in Eclipse RCP (Helios) sometimes I would get this error. Does anyone have any idea what it's about? I've googled and searched everywhere - but have no idea what it is!

> An error occurred while collecting
>   items to be installed session context
>   was:(profile=epp.package.rcp,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect,
>   operand=, action=). No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh,3.2.100.I20090508-2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *looks* a plugin you have installed is dependent on version 3.2.100.I20090508-2000 of ssh plugin, and Eclipse is having trouble fetching it (or you have that plugin installed directly).

Now... *why* that's happening is anyone's guess. Maybe somewhere in your "plugin tree" that particular dependency is set incorrectly. Maybe you've just got general network issues (firewall or proxy settings, for instance).

Have you installed extra plugins? Is it possible for you to go back to a vanilla install of whatever Eclipse version you're using? You could then start re-adding plugins one by one until you're either where you need to be environment wise or you are able to narrow down the problem to one plugin.

Best I can do is offer more troubleshooting tips... sorry.

Comment: I don't even have "org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh" plugin installed. I only have "org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh2 (3.2.300.I20100526-0800)". The only software I have installed is "Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers" and "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required)"

Comment: Weird - I just downloaded "Ecplise RCP 64bit", and it works there!

Comment: Haha... well... I assume you're on a 64 bit OS then? Problem solved?

Comment: Yes but originally this problem was on 32-bit eclipse with 32-bit JDK.